# How to fix glitching google icons?

Tags: windows, tampermonkey, openjdk-17

After installing jdk-17_windows-x64_bin.exe, this issue started occuring. I do not know how to fix it. I can't even run tampermonkey properly.[The glitching google icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X51UU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be issue between Chrome and graphics drivers. Try refreshing the page, it resolves most of the time for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).